# Ignore ExpandoObject Properties with JSON.Net Serializer Settings

Tags: json.net, edgejs

Is it possible to ignore `ExpandoObject` properties, in particular those of `Delegate` type, when using `JsonConvert(expando, formatting, serializerSettings)`?

Essentially I'm trying to ignore all parsing of the `func` property in this example expando object:

```
//{
//  func: () => {}
//}
Action func = () => {};
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.func = func;

// should be empty object {}
string json = JsonConvert(expando, formatting, serializerSettings);
```

The first thing I tried was overriding the converter.  Unfortunately this doesn't work, as I see `CanConvert` called recursively for `Action` -> `DelegateEntry` -> some generic type -> `RuntimeMethodInfo`.

```
    private class ExpandoObjectIgnoreConverter : ExpandoObjectConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            if (typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return base.CanConvert(objectType);
        }
    }
```

A method that works is using an error handler in serialization settings and a contract resolver. When I throw the error, all further processing of the property is ignored, i.e. `Action` <strike>-> `DelegateEntry` -> some generic type -> `RuntimeMethodInfo`</strike>. However, I'd like to do this more elegantly than throwing an exception if possible.

Error handler:

```
        serializationSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.ErrorContext.Error is InvalidCastException)
            {
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Contract resolver:

```
    private class ExpandoObjectContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
        {
            if (typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException();
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ResolveContract(type);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using the [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) library to script nodejs from within a C# process. I'm trying to remove functions from the returned javascript objects from within C#, as they are assigned a `Delegate` type that doesn't play nicely with `JsonConvert`.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what your problem is.  Are you trying to skip delegate-valued `ExpandoObject` properties when *serializing*?  Because it also sounds like you are trying to deserialize this sample json: `{
  func: () => {}
}`, which is invalid.

Comment: Updated that part to make it more clear, it's during serialization of the expando to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) does not have any custom code to *write* an `ExpandoObject`.  Instead it overrides [`JsonConverter.CanWrite`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) to return `false` thereby allowing the expando to be serialized generically as an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Thus you can override `CanWrite` and [`WriteJson()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) yourself to filter undesired key/value pairs before serialization:

```
public class FilteredExpandoObjectConverter : ExpandoObjectConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var expando = (IDictionary<string, object>)value;
        var dictionary = expando
            .Where(p => !(p.Value is System.Delegate))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dictionary);
    }
}
```

Then use the converter in settings as follows:

```
var formatting = Formatting.Indented;
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new FilteredExpandoObjectConverter() },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expando, formatting, serializerSettings);
```

Note this will only filter delegates values directly owned by an `ExpandoObject`.  If you have a collection containing some delegates, or delegate-valued members in some POCO, they will not be filtered by this code.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xwg9Fy).